# Emacs right click context menu on Mac OS

Tags: emacs

Is there any good reason that Mac Emacs does not bind the right mouse click to the context menu. Instead, ctrl-mouse-left-button must be clicked.

Any customization to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the global menu, `File`, `Edit`, etc.

So I used `describe key` with `C-h k <right-click>`, which links to `mouse.el`. There, I notice a section

```
;;; Bindings for mouse commands.
```

which I inspect since I want the behavior of `C-<right-click>` replicated in `<right-click>`.

I find

```
(global-set-key [C-down-mouse-3]
  `(menu-item ,(purecopy "Menu Bar") ignore
    :filter (lambda (_)
              (if (zerop (or (frame-parameter nil 'menu-bar-lines) 0))
                  (mouse-menu-bar-map)
                (mouse-menu-major-mode-map)))))
```

and simply add this to my `init.el`, changing `(global-set-key [C-down-mouse-3]...` to `(global-set-key [mouse-3]...`